# Take the address of an image from the database and use it to direct to a file in server

Tags: php, html

```
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row['cnvts']; ?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row['image']; ?><a href='others/$row['image']'></div></td>
```

This is a part of the html query inorder where the content column image is been is been displayed.

So here now am planning to display the image that is been saved the folder "Other" with the name mohar.jpg

So is it possible to give a link in html to retrive the data from the filed image in db table and use it to open the image while clicking on it

Answer (score 0):

I might have miss understood your question, but you are asking if there is a way to display an image from a saved url / path you fetched from DB right? If so, then the answer is simply

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
```

This of course imples that $row['image'] contains a valid relative path, like "/Other/mohar.jpg" - if not you need to massage it in PHP before sending it into the HTML.

Edit: After looking more closely over your question, I realize you might simply ask how you make a link out of an image in HTML, in that case you need two things. The URL to the image, and the URL to the pdf file (or target of the link). I assume you have the link to the pdf file from the DB row named $row['pdf']:

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['pdf']; ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" /> </a>
```

Have a look at this Fiddle for a accurate example:
http://jsfiddle.net/z7gS4/2/

Also, you could read about [linking images in HTML here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_imglink)

Comment: sir thankyou for answering....   sir actually trying to dispaly a pdf file on clicking the link. that is been displayed.

Comment: in our project have written the code for entering the pdf into the database.....  but now the real problem is to retrive the uploaded pdf from the database. the uploaded pdf is automatically stored  in a folder named others with a name. so when the admin sees this entry in admins page he should be able to open the pdf to check what is been uploaded. so in the admins page we have retrive all the field details from the table and for the admin the page should be displayed with the image cell content as a link to display the uploaded pdf on click

Comment: So, my advice is to store the path to the .pdf file in the database so that you only store a string with a relative path like "Others/mohar.pdf" in the DB; and then you just link it in the HTML. The browser will handle opening / displaying the pdf.

Comment: how to link it html?  am srry sir i am a beginner

Comment: I struggle to understand the problem. =) [Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7gS4/), is this what you are asking about?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<a href="others/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" target="_blank">link</a>
```